# why allshortestpath so slow?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I create some graph database with python and neo4j library. Graph have 50k nodes and 100k relationships.

How creating nodes:

```
CREATE (user:user {task_id: %s, id: %s, root: 1, private: 0})
```

How creating relationships:

```
 MATCH (root_user), (friend_user) WHERE root_user.id = %s
                                  AND root_user.task_id = %s  
                                  AND friend_user.id = %s
                                  AND friend_user.task_id = %s
                    CREATE (root_user)-[r: FRIEND_OF]->(friend_user) RETURN root_user, friend_user
```

How i search all path between nodes:

```
MATCH (start_user:user {id: %s, task_id: %s}), 
      (end_user:user {id: %s, task_id: %s}), 
      path = allShortestPaths((start_user)-[*..3]-(end_user)) RETURN path
```

Soo its very slow, around 30-60 min on 50k graph. And i cant understand why. I try to create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :user(id, task_id)
```

but its not help. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please run a PROFILE on the query (or at the very least an EXPLAIN, but a PROFILE would be much better), expand all elements, and add the plan to your question. Also if you have query logging enabled, please grab an excerpt of the query from the log with its timings and add it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should never generate a long Cypher query that contains N slight variations of essentially the same Cypher code. That is very slow and takes up a lot of memory.

Instead, you should be passing [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) to a much simpler Cypher query.

For example, when creating your nodes, you could pass a `data` parameter to the following Cypher code:

```
UNWIND $data AS d
CREATE (user:user {task_id: d.taskId, id: d.id, root: 1, private: 0})
```

The `data` parameter value that you pass would be a list of maps, and each map would contain a `taskId` and `id`. The `UNWIND` clause "unwinds" the `data` list into individual `d` maps. This would be much faster.

Something similar needs to be done with your relationship-creation code.

In addition, in order to use any of your `:user` indexes, your `MATCH` clause MUST specify the `:user` label in the relevant node patterns. Otherwise, you are asking Cypher to scan all nodes, regardless of label, and that kind of processing would not be able to take advantage of indexes. For example, the relevant query should start with:

```
MATCH (root_user:user), (friend_user:user)
...
```

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks for answer. Yep, im replace my relationship code to this, moment ago:

"""
MATCH (root_user:user {id: %s, task_id: %s}), 
             (friend_user:user {id: %s, task_id: %s})  
CREATE (root_user)-[r: FRIEND_OF]->(friend_user) RETURN root_user, friend_user 
"""

but i cant say that is faster.


About
"""UNWIND $data AS d"""


its not equal to python string format like "%s" % variable?

Comment: No, it is very different.